# C++ header file referencing a struct defined below

Tags: c++, struct, header-files, declaration

What is considered the best practice for handling this situation?

```
class A {
    private:
        std::vector<B> derp;
    public:
        struct B { ... };
        void foo(B b);
}
```

(The problem is that this code would say "error: use of undeclared identifier 'B'"
I think I could solve the problem by doing something like

```
class A {
    public:
        struct B { ... };
        void foo(B b);
    private:
        std::vector<B> derp;
}
```

But that seems strange and not like the proper solution.  Also as a side note, if I were to write that should I write it like this?

```
struct A {
    struct B { ... };
    void foo(B b);

    private:
        std::vector<B> derp;
}
```

Comment: i would say to create the B class and include it later in the Class A declaration.

Comment: Do you ant people to be able to create instances of `B` or should it be something only accessible to your `A`?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a forward declaration of `B` before declaring `derp` if you don't want to move the definition of `B` before declaring `derp`.

```
class A {
   public:
      struct B;
   private:
      std::vector<B> derp;
   public:
      struct B { ... };
      void foo(B b);
};
```

However, from a physical layout perspective, the `public` section of a class shoud be before its `private` section. You want the `public` section to be seen by a user first.

Given that, I think it'll be better to use:

```
class A {
    public:
        struct B { ... };
        void foo(B b);
    private:
        std::vector<B> derp;
};
```

That solves the problem of `B` not being declared/defined before the declaration of the member variable `derp`. It also puts the `public` section ahead of the `private` section.

Comment: It's undefined behavior to create `std::vector` of incomplete type.

Answer (score 0):

Just like variables, you can forward-declare classes and structures.  For example, in your case you can do the following:

```
class A {
public:
    struct B;
private:
    std::vector<B> derp;
public:
    struct B { ... };
    void foo( B b );
};
```

Keep in mind if you forward-declare a class or structure within a class, you need to declare it with the same access level (private/protected/public) as you define it later.